# Weird error deploying Azure Container Instances

Tags: docker, azure-container-instances

I am trying to run Docker image from the Docker Hub in the Azure Container Instances but deployment always fails in some reason. The repository on Docker Hub is public. The service says that the image has been successfully pulled but it pulls it again and again and the state of the container is always "Waiting". The image must not be broken because I can create the container and use it locally without any problems.
(please ignore different tags on screenshot)
[image: Deployment details]

What could be a reason?

[image: Container status]

Answer (score 2):

Is the default command for your container a long-running process? Usually, this behavior indicates that the container is starting and immediately exiting, triggering the service to try and start it again, over and over.

Comment: And if so, it is just a [default behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-troubleshooting#container-continually-exits-and-restarts), changed by specifying `--restart-policy never` or `--restart-policy onfailure`.

Might be a good way to go with console apps.

Comment: Sean is likely correct - it looks like your container is repeatedly exiting and due to a default restart policy of always, the container will just keep coming back up as it detects a successful run. Try psfinaki's suggestion to verify.